# @iPhone : how to create twitter + OAuth custom login in our application

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios4, twitter-oauth

I am making iphone application. In that I am integrating Twiiter using OAuth.

My question is I want my own login page and not provided by twitter as in new OAuth integration the twitter is providing.

Is the same possible to create & pass username and password to the twitter for accessing twitter by making custom login page in new OAuth

if any one knowing please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot create your own login page.

OAuth is a mechanism that allows users to access a service via a 3rd party without sharing their credentials and if you were able to create your own login page, you would handle the credentials yourself and that's not what Twitter wants.

**Edit:** 
Twitter offers an alternative called xAuth. Here is a statement from [TweetDeck](http://support.tweetdeck.com/entries/229056-iphone-and-ipad-tweetdecks-updated-for-basic-auth-switch-off). If you want to use xAuth you will have to register your application with Twitter to obtain a key to sign your requests. [More information here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth)

Comment: fine and thanks for you reply but the application like tweet deck and other application for twitter providing credentials by their own way. how those things are happening? they are also need to use OAuth but they are using their own login methods and not provided by twitter + Oauth. Can you please let me know how such things are happening?

Comment: They use xAuth, I've edited my original answer, please take a look at it.