# Twitter + SAOAuthTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

So, I have been reading into the whole OAuth stuff the recent days, trying to find something to help me authenticate with twitter. Since most of the topics in this forum pointed to Ben Gottliebs [Framework](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) I tried to include it in my TestApp which went fine.

Inserting my tokens, logging in went easy. Next thing I wanted to do, was using my own login screen. So I have to replace the Webview which is used with my own (e.g.) UIView.

The thing is, I couldn't find out how to do that. I have absolutely no idea at what point 'interfere' since everything is so obscure (on purpose?)...

So my questions are:

1) Has anyone approached the issue in any way and can you give me a hint on what there is to do?
2) Is is generally ok to change the framework in that way? I couldn't find anything which would prohibit me of doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea behind OAuth is that you don't provide the login screen. That way, the user doesn't have to give you his password. Instead, he is taken out of your app temporarily, passed to Twitter (or Facebook, or whatever), authenticated with them, and then Twitter (or Facebook, or whatever) gives you a token that you can use for as long as the user still gives you permission to use it.

That all being said, Twitter does actually provide a way for you to customize your own login screen, called xAuth. However, you need special permission from Twitter to get access to create an xAuth app.

Information about xAuth: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth

Another Question about this: [@iPhone : how to create twitter + OAuth custom login in our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751239/iphone-how-to-create-twitter-oauth-custom-login-in-our-application)

Comment: Hm, must have missed the whole point from it then. Will check xAuth. Thanks for the answer.