# In IOS 5 how do we login to twitter from our application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, twitter

All the tutorial I found explains how to tweet and show an alert message if users cannot tweet.

What about if user hasn't logged in to twitter yet and I want to help user logged in to tweeter.

Basically we want to allow user to sign up to our services via facebook and twitter. We've taken care of facebook. Now we need to so it for twitter.

This are samples of tutorial I found
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

I don't want to tweet. I just want to login first so I can store the users' twitter id on my database allowing it to save bookmarks, etc..

All I see is https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios. It's not clear whether we have to compute the sig manually, do we have to open safari or what.

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through [api documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios) on twitter integration to ios?

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751239/iphone-how-to-create-twitter-oauth-custom-login-in-our-application?rq=1).May be this will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to login with their twitter accounts, you will have to register your application with Twitter to obtain a key to sign your requests. You can read more about this on [Twitter Developer Page](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth)

Comment: Actually in facebook we call that request permission.

Comment: Well, both have their own standards to follow.

Comment: Okay I already did that. Then what? What I see is things like https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios no sample code. Nothing.

Comment: check out this for mobile development discussions https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/mobile-development   Also, please go through this page to learn more about [XAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)